# Typescript return type of unknown merge of objects

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes an unknown of objects and I want to output a merged version of them:

```
export function merge(...objects: any[]) {
  return objects.reduce((acc, current) => {
    acc = {
      ...acc,
      ...current
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
}


const a = { name: '' };
const b = { id: 1 };
const c = { prop: '' };

const result = merge(a, b, c);
```

How can I automatically infer the type of the `result` variable based on the passed objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `objects` array component type is a union of the individual object types, and your result is like an intersection, so here is a solution using the union-to-intersection transformation from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/12299000).

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

type Merge<A extends any[]> = UnionToIntersection<A[number]>
```

Usage:

```
function merge<A extends any[]>(...objects: A): Merge<A> {
    // ...
}

const result = merge({ a: 1 }, { b: 'foo' }, { c: 2, d: 'bar' });
// result: { a: number } & { b: string } & { c: number, d: string }
```

The result is practically equivalent to `{ a: number, b: string, c: number, d: string }` but unfortunately Typescript doesn't simplify it.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCpIJJ2BATgZwgGNhk4AeGAPigF4oAoKKAChiggA8c4ATfKAEM4IKAH5WAawBcsAJS0qANyQJeUWXAhK8cjtwh8BLFjKgI4AMzxQMC5at56JGDVC07cDBqEhQAsngA5hDkAIL6PPxCIgDaALo09PBk6Fg4BMSkKOGxcACuALYARniJ3pb5cCRkUIXBoRFcUQLCIAlULAB0PUjFAFZZ+LJhcrKBuCHhNADeTFC4EMD5uHBQfYMk+F2LvPlEECaCREQANFBEK4vYeopQc8zMx0R09-OPUD1dz6fvj1+XXDXYB-AC+f0Wy1WQhOAG55qDzjNQXJ4eCGEQUPhgAsIPh8gAbHH0eqTQ4zISyACMUER9ygxVkAHJLEgkEzaUiLrIAEznXjM4qCXAclHwgD04tx+KJsgpgk0RVKuFpUAAZPTGVBsbgLEFVRqKURFSU8PzZDq9bSGEA)